# how to use condition to show a specific alertdialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some category, so when x category is selected it is necessary that the Alert Dialog showing a specific inputs.

```
                   child: Text(
                                  'Demande de prix',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.white,
                                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2664B5),
                                  onSurface: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (categorielist ==
                                      betonpretalemploilist)
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            DemandeDevis2(),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  else {
                                    return DemandeDevis();
                                  }
                                },
                              )),
                            ),`
```

Comment: Try formatting your question a little better. Maybe have a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always use a ternary expression or an if condition to display a specific widget.

Below is a small example of how to use if conditions to display a widget or a ternary expression to display a specific widget.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool displayText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            if (displayText)
              Text(
                'This text is displayed if displayText is true',
              ),
            displayText
                ? Text(
                    'This text is displayed if displayText is true',
                  )
                : Text(
                    'This text is displayed if displayText is false',
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ,i think this is not useful for me because i need a condition of navigation when x categorie is selected show alertDialog 1 else show alertDialog 2

Comment: You can probably use the same logic to select the Navigator you want to use.
Also, you may want to use `onRouteGenerated` if you switch between multiples `Navigator`